# Laravel singleton is always giving new instance

Tags: singleton, laravel-6

AppServiceProvider.php :

```
    public function register()
{
    $this->app->singleton('FacebookConversionConfigService', function($app)
    {
        return new FacebookConversionConfigService();
    });
}
```

FacebookConversionConfigService.php :

```
class FacebookConversionConfigService {

    public function __construct() {
        \Log::debug(rand(0, 999999));
        \Log::debug(spl_object_id($this));
    }
}
```

Controller :

```
(resolve(FacebookConversionConfigService::class));
(resolve(FacebookConversionConfigService::class));
```

And in the log i get different data:

```
[2021-05-17 14:56:56] local.DEBUG: 516  
[2021-05-17 14:56:56] local.DEBUG: 431890  
[2021-05-17 14:56:56] local.DEBUG: 564  
[2021-05-17 14:56:56] local.DEBUG: 132296  
[2021-05-17 14:56:56] local.DEBUG: 519  
[2021-05-17 14:56:56] local.DEBUG: 469242  
[2021-05-17 14:56:56] local.DEBUG: 589  
[2021-05-17 14:56:56] local.DEBUG: 543196  
[2021-05-17 14:56:56] local.DEBUG: 601
```

But it should be the same. Why every time constructor is called? In singleton it should be called only one time. I have tried resolve(), app(), but same thing.

Answer (score -1):

It needs to write:

```
$this->app->singleton(FacebookConversionConfigService::class, function($app)
```

instead of:

```
$this->app->singleton('FacebookConversionConfigService', function($app)
```